# Windows 7: Merge network drive and local partition

Tags: windows, windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, network-shares

(When I speak of "distributed data storage" in this question I mean *literally* distributing the data so half is on one disk/folder and half is on the other)

Both computers in my situation are 32-bit and running Windows 7 Pro and Ultimate, both upgraded to Service Pack 1. Both partitions which I wish to merge are NTFS-formatted and ~300GB in size. The computer running Windows 7 Pro will be used for hosting a light Git server, and the Windows 7 Ultimate computer will be used for providing additional storage via Ethernet.

The computer running Windows 7 Ultimate is the "slave" - it is a very minimal environment, 32-bit, ~2GB RAM, but 350GB of free space. So I cut the disk into one 50GB partition for Windows and one 300GB partition to function as my network disk. I enabled sharing on the 300GB partition and am able to access and write to it from my Windows 7 Pro machine over Ethernet.

The Windows 7 Pro machine (the "master" which will be hosting the Git server) is a little more powerful, still 32-bit, but with a better CPU and ~2.5GB RAM. This machine also has a 50GB partition dedicated to Windows and a secondary 350GB partition.

**What I wish to do is combine the network drive from the slave with the 350GB partition on the master, so that both are considered as one by the operating system.** The Git server software I will be using, [Gitea](https://gitea.io), does not support distributed data storage (as far as I know, at least).

**What I've already tried (everything run in admin command prompt):**

- `mklink /D "{master's 350GB partition}:\" "\\{slave}\{networkdisk}"` returns `Access is denied`.
- `mklink /D "{master's 350GB partition}:\{any folder name}" "\\{slave}\{networkdisk}"` works, but is not my solution (since, again, my server software does not support distributing data storage among multiple drives/folders.)
- `net use "{master's 350GB partition}:\" "\\{slave}\{networkdisk}" * /user:{username} /persistent:yes` says "the local device name is already in use".
- Obviously, mapping the network share as a drive via Windows Explorer GUI. Still no fish.

TL;DR: **How can I merge a network partition and a local partition into one if they are both NTFS-formatted?** (exFAT solutions work too)

P.S. I've been thinking, there might be a way I can use VHDs. I might be able to store one part of the VHD on my slave and the other half on my master, and somehow get Windows to think that the two are one virtual disk when mounted. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think I was getting at something like *RAID-over-Ethernet*, which I frankly don't think is possible on Windows 7. It would have been terribly slow too, since the network speed was ~11MB/s anyway.

Simply said, the answer to my question is **just don't.**